# Create stored procedure in DocumentDB Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Update:  I downloaded the emulator again and did a repair and the options show up again.  Resolved.

can anyone please tell me if it is possible to create stored procedures in DocumentDB emulator?  I know I can do it in the real DocumentDB on Azure.  However, I can't seem to be able to find the script panel anywhere in the emulator.  I google around and I can't find any answer either. According to the website, I should be able to create stored procs using the emulator.  Very strange.

Comment: @Matias:  So strange.  I have tried the 3 dots and I only had 2 options available.  Delete collection and new document.  I never see the other options you see.  I downloaded my emulator from azure website as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can create stored procedure using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, the following code works fine on my side.

**Register stored procedure**

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
    new Uri("https://localhost:8081"),
    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
var TestSproc = new StoredProcedure
{
    Id = "SayHello",
    Body = @"function SayHello() { 
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    response.setBody('hello');}"
};
StoredProcedure createdStoredProcedure = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll"), TestSproc);
```

**Execute stored procedure**

```
StoredProcedureResponse<object> result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(
    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("testdb", "testcoll", "SayHello"));

result.Response.ToString();
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  I know I can use the DocumentDB api to create a stored procedure.   I was wondering if I could create a stored procedure in the emulator.  At the mean time, I would go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Stored procedures, User Defined Functions & Triggers from the Cosmos DB Emulator UI. Just click on the `...` dots that appear when you hover over the collection to open the context menu or right click over it.

[image: Azure Cosmos DB Emulator capture]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Do you mind showing me the link where you downloaded the emulator from?  I downloaded  the emulator from Azure website and somehow I got only 2 options when I clicked on the 3 dots.

Comment: Are you clicking on the dots near the collection name? Did you try with right-click?Downloaded from the [official docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) :)